# Should I edit an answer just to retrieve the downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I downvoted an answer. After some time, I reconsidered my downvote and decided to retrieve it. But I can not retrieve it until it is updated.

So, I made some minor adjustments to the answer (no improvement at all). And after that, I can retrieve the downvote.

Is it a good behavior?

Comment: `minor adjustments` If these edits are useful (and not just superfluous cosmetic changes) then I don't see any issue with it. Just be careful of not making useless annoying edits.

Comment: Can you *retrieve* a downvote? Isn't it *retract*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I kicked a downvote over the fence the other day, but my kindly neighbour let me go into her garden to retrieve it.